# How to listen to custom events on all windows, bubbling issue?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, listener, dom-events, event-bubbling

I'm trying to listen to custom event 'peakAhBoo' so I add the event listener to `gBrowser` and if no `gBrowser` is present then I add it to `aDOMWindow` ([gist](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9288991)).

Code snippet:

```
loadIntoWindow: function (aDOMWindow, aXULWindow) {
  if (!aDOMWindow) {
    return;
  }
  if (aDOMWindow.gBrowser) {
    aDOMWindow.gBrowser.addEventListener('peakAhBoo', respondToCustomEvent_peakAhBoo, true);
  } else {
    aDOMWindow.addEventListener('peakAhBoo', respondToCustomEvent_peakAhBoo, true);
  }
},
```

Code to dispatch event:

```
var myEvent = new CustomEvent('peakAhBoo', {
    'detail': {
        'hazcheeseburger': true
    }
});
var myEvent = window.document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
var myEventDetail = {hello:'world'};
myEvent.initCustomEvent('peakAhBoo', true, true, myEventDetail);
window.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
```

However if I open scratchpad and run this create/dispatch event code from environment content, its not bubbling up to `gBrowser`. If I run it in browser environment it never hits the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, now i see what you mean, but according to MDN you need to use this:

```
document.addEventListener("MyExtensionEvent", function(e) { myExtension.myListener(e); }, false, true);
// The last value is a Mozilla-specific value to indicate untrusted content is allowed to trigger the event
```

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Interaction_between_privileged_and_non-privileged_pages

I tested it and it works!

web page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="main-content"><button onclick="trigger()">Trigger custom event</button></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function trigger(){
            var myEvent = new CustomEvent('peakAhBoo', {
                'detail': {
                    'hazcheeseburger': true
                }
            });
            var myEvent = window.document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
            var myEventDetail = {hello:'world'};
            myEvent.initCustomEvent('peakAhBoo', true, true, myEventDetail);
            window.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
            console.log(myEvent)
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and in privileged code:

```
function respondToCustomEvent_peakAhBoo(e){
    console.log('g: '+e.target);
}

gBrowser.addEventListener("peakAhBoo", respondToCustomEvent_peakAhBoo, false, true);
```

Comment: Oh my gosh spectacular!! That 4th argument was a sneaky one!! Note for others. **Note 1** On removeEventListener there is no 4th argument so just remove it like normal. **Note 2** If you set this 4th argument to TRUE, then if you dispatch the event from browser context it will not trigger, so you will have to add a second addEventListener with 4th set to FALSE, *BUT I don't know if the two event listeners can coexist? I think the one that is addedLast overwrites the first*, what do you @M.J. Saedy?

Comment: i don't think we're supposed to do that ;-)

Comment: Ah you mean listen to event from both privelaged and non-privelaged? They only want us listening to one or the other so not to mix trsuted content?