# CustomEvent error in Firefox bootstrapped addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless

From [document.createEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createEvent)

> The createEvent method is deprecated. Use [event
>   constructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent)
>   instead.

In `bootstap.js`

```
// this works
let event = window.document.createEvent('Event');
event.initEvent('main-unload',false,false);
window.dispatchEvent(event);

// this doesn't work
let event = new CustomEvent('main-unload', {"detail":{"hazcheeseburger":true}});
window.dispatchEvent(event);
//Console error: 1404023846296  addons.xpi  WARN    Exception running bootstrap method shutdown on ***addon-id****
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Custom events from addon scope is tricky initially, there's this 4th argument on `addEventListener`. Check out this topic: [How to listen to custom events on all windows, bubbling issue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22121652/how-to-listen-to-custom-events-on-all-windows-bubbling-issue)

Comment: @Noitidart Correct, but that only applies when a privileged context (`bootstrap.js`, overlay script, etc.) wants to listen to events dispatched by an unprivileged website, so it doesn't really apply here.

Comment: It might be a good idea to enclose `startup`/`shutdown` in try-catch blocks that `Cu.reportError` any exceptions. Makes it easier to figure out *what* code is broken. The regualar `addons.xpi WARN` message is not really helpful in that regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `CustomEvent` constructor. The `bootstrap.js` code does not have one of those, only windows do.

The following should work:

```
let event = new (window.CustomEvent)('main-unload',
                                     {"detail":{"hazcheeseburger":true}});
```