# initCustomEvent pass data for method doesn't work anymore

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I wrote a firefox extension and for interation data between privilege and non-privilege pages I use this snipped code

```
    //Listen for the event
    window.addEventListener("MyEvent", function(evt) {
        console.log(evt.detail);
    }, false);

    //Dispatch an event
    var evt = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
    evt.initCustomEvent("MyEvent", true, true, {
      name : 'activate',
      method : function() {
        //...
      }    
    });
    window.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

and everything go well after I update my FireFox to version 32.0.1, at this time my FireFox doesn't work and I try to find the error and discover that the method I passed to MyEvent always null. Why?

Is it possible that in the new version of FireFox I couldn't pass function any more or I should do something newer for solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to use [__exposedProps__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_bindings/XPConnect/XPConnect_wrappers#__exposedProps__).

Like

```js
var detail = {
  name: "activate",
  method: function(){},
  __exposedProps__: {method: "r"}
};
```

Needless to say that, unless you are absolutely sure that you know what you 're doing, this is a security risk.

Comment: Wow interesting stuff I didn't know this. @AKZ let us know if this fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure things used to work before?

You need to set the 4th argument of `addEventListener` to `true`. Argument is called `wantsUntrusted`.

[MDN :: addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FEventTarget.addEventListener)

Also see this topic here: [How to listen to custom events on all windows, bubbling issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22121652/how-to-listen-to-custom-events-on-all-windows-bubbling-issue)

So try this:

```
//Listen for the event
window.addEventListener("MyEvent", function(evt) {
    console.log(evt.detail);
}, false, true);

//Dispatch an event
var evt = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
evt.initCustomEvent("MyEvent", true, true, {
  name : 'activate',
  method : function() {
    //...
  }    
});
window.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Comment: Yes, It does work before anyway I tried add true as last arguments but it doesn't work either

Comment: Oh I see your problem, you arent able to pass a function. Hmm Im not sure about that one.