# Firefox Addon SDK message from chrome to unprivileged code

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to pass messages between a Firefox Addon worker script and the webpage's javascript. I found [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Interaction_between_privileged_and_non-privileged_pages) which explains how to send a message to the script and get a reply back, but I want to simply send the message from chrome to the unprivileged code. I have already tried using the following two methods.

I am sending from a worker attached to a panel and I want to receive the message in some javascript that I have injected into the page DOM.

To send

```
    var element = document.createElement("MyExtensionDataElement");
    element.setAttribute('detail', "hi");
    document.documentElement.appendChild(element);
    console.log("created the event", element);

    var evt = document.createEvent("Events");
    evt.initEvent("MyExtensionEvent1", true, false);
    element.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

To receive

```
    document.addEventListener("MyExtensionEvent", function(e) {
        myExtension.myListener(e);
    }, false, true);
```

And also via a simple `CustomEvent`

To send

```
var e = new CustomEvent("event",{detail:"string here"});
window.dispatchEvent(e);
```

To recieve

```
    window.addEventListener("event",function(e){
        console.log(e.detail);
    });
```

The first one sends the message but it isnt received, and the second one fails to even create the CustomEvent in the first place. I'd appreciate any help on this matter and do apologize if the question seems amateurish. Im new to Firefox Addon Development.

Answer (score 0):

Your receive is wrong, you need to use add 4th argument and set it to try:

So

```
window.addEventListener("event",function(e){
    console.log(e.detail);
});
```

Goes to

```
window.addEventListener("event",function(e){
    console.log(e.detail);
}, false, true);
```

See this topic - [initCustomEvent pass data for method doesn't work anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821780/initcustomevent-pass-data-for-method-doesnt-work-anymore/25822988#25822988)