# Firefox Addon addEventListener not catching event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Im making a Firefox Addon in FF42 using the Addon SDK. I've also included an AngularJS app in the Addon, and in the app.js file, I've created an Event Listener as so

```
window.addEventListener("updateSimpleStorage", function($obj) {
    console.log('updateSimpleStorage: ', $obj);
    private_self_options.simpleStorage = $obj.detail;
});
```

and in my script.js I am sending out an Event as so

```
var e = new CustomEvent('updateSimpleStorage', {'detail': simpleStorage});
window.dispatchEvent(e);
```

So why is it that the eventlistener doesnt pick up on the event? Please point out my mistake? I feel its a scope issue but I cant put my finger on it.

Comment: Very cool, I have also done some angular work - https://github.com/Noitidart/ZooniverseXpert - and also in my preferences panel here - https://github.com/Noitidart/MouseControl - Ill take a stab at answering your question now.

Answer (score 2):

There is a 3rd and 4th argument to `addEventListener`.

The 3rd one you are familiar with, its the `useCapture`. The 4th one is criticial in this case, because you want to capture events from unprivileged code. So you must set that to `true`.

See these topics:

- [How to listen to custom events on all windows, bubbling issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22121652/how-to-listen-to-custom-events-on-all-windows-bubbling-issue)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25822988/1828637